# Facebook manual link sharing disregards og:image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page with a fb share widget and sharing via this one the image associated with the link correctly gets read from my `<meta property="og:image" ...`.

However, when a user manually pastes a link to the page on facebook, the associated thumbnail is not taken from the meta tag, but there are images from the page available for selection.

Shouldn't the meta tag overwrite that behaviour and only my selected og:image be available? How can I make my specified image the default also for manual link sharing?

Comment: Yes, it should work that way. Have you checked your URL for errors? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Thanks - I had previously check that and saw the correct image preview, as it shows when sharing form the page. However, there was a note that the og:image should be bigger - that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging via http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug there is a message:

> Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed
>
> og:image should be larger:    Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 and preferably 1500x1500. (Maximum image size is 5MB.) Image 'htt...jpg' will be used instead.

It turns out my small icon image was good for the sharing on page, but the manual sharing of a link on facebook requires a big enough image to use that defined image instead of any image fetched from the page.